# Android DataItem Not syncing with emulator wearable

Tags: android, android-emulator, data-synchronization, android-wear-data-api, dataitem

I have been googling for 5 straight days and still can't find the solution to my problem so I desperately publish my question in the hope that somebody can help me.

I've been trying to send a DataItem to an emulator wearable through the WearableAPI. I will describe all the steps i'm following and specify the code I wrote.

Thanks in advance!

1. I start the emulator.
2. I open Android Wear app on my own device and pair up the emulator.
3. I forward the ADB through adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601 in the platform-tools folder.
4. I start the mobile app on my phone through Android Studio
5. I start the wear app on the emulator through Android Studio
6. I wait for something to happen but nothing happens.

Mobile Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    initComponents();
}


private void initComponents() {
    ...
    initWearLink();
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}


// ---------------------------- WEARABLE PART ----------------------------

private void initWearLink() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            // Request access only to the Wearable API
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();
    increaseCounter();
}


private static final String COUNT_KEY = "efficiencyaide.dev.pv.studea.count";

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private int count = 0;


// Create a data map and put data in it
private void increaseCounter() {
    PutDataMapRequest putDataMapReq = PutDataMapRequest.create("/count");
    putDataMapReq.getDataMap().putInt(COUNT_KEY, count++);
    PutDataRequest putDataReq = putDataMapReq.asPutDataRequest();
    PendingResult<DataApi.DataItemResult> pendingResult =
            Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, putDataReq.setUrgent());
}


@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
    public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEventBuffer) {

}
```

Mobile Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="efficiencyaide.dev.pv.studea">
<meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    tools:replace="android:icon"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">>


    <activity
        android:name=".newapp.activities.StartSplashScreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Mobile gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "efficiencyaide.dev.pv.studea"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories {
maven {
    url "https://jitpack.io"
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
wearApp project(':wear')

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.6'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
compile 'com.github.jivimberg:autoresizetextview:0.0.2'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

---

Wearable Code:

```
 private void initWear() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .enableAutoManage(this,this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i("Test", "Connected");
    Wearable.DataApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Wearable.DataApi.removeListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
    for (DataEvent event : dataEvents) {
        if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
            // DataItem changed
            DataItem item = event.getDataItem();
            if (item.getUri().getPath().compareTo("/count") == 0) {
                DataMap dataMap = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(item).getDataMap();
                updateCount(dataMap.getInt(COUNT_KEY));
            }
        } else if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_DELETED) {
            // DataItem deleted
        }
    }
}
```

Wearable Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="efficiencyaide.dev.pv.studea">

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <activity
        android:name=".TaskWorkWatchFace"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".TaskSuggestionWatchFace"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</manifest>
```

(Sorry for the long post/code but i didn't want to miss anything out)

What I already know/debugged:

1. The onDataChanged() function is never called
2. The onConnected() function in the wearable device is never called
3. If I start the app on the wearable, it says: "*new version of Google Play services is needed. It will update itself shortly*". After this message, the app starts.
4. [EDIT]: Setting ADB debuggin enabled does not help.

I hope that somebody can help me with this information. I apologize for the amount of code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: +1 for the format of your startup question :) is this only with emulator have you tested it on real environment ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I've just tested it and indeed it works on my real wearable device (I should've thought about that). So what am I doing wrong with the emulator? Again thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have had the exact same issue yesterday and couldn't find out why.

Today I started everything up again and found [this](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/49586/how-do-i-connect-an-android-wear-emulator-to-a-real-phone/) link that showed me how to connect the wearable emulator to the phone. I did everything before I found this link, except for 1 thing: enable ADB debugging on the wearable.

In the end, this was causing my problems of connectivity.

To the point: Enable ADB debugging on the emulator to make it work.

To do this, go to options --> find "about" --> click a few times on "Build number" --> go back to options --> developer options --> enable ADB debugging.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I already did this (I should've posted that in my question) and this won't work either. I did a full reset on the wearable and enabled the debugging options but with no succes.

Comment: The only thing I can think of now is moving that meta-data line of code towards your activity... Could you try this for me? Also, are notifications shared? are notifications popping up at the emulator? if so, the problem is not caused by the connection but something else... you could also try if the DataLayer sample works...

Comment: I moved the <meta-data> tag inside the <activity> of wearable and mobile device but still no luck. Also, the emulator is functioning exactly (i.e. receives notifications) as my real wearable with the only difference that my own app does not receive the DataItem. I will look into the DataLayer sample. Thank you for your response!